# Bootstrap 4 - how to detect changes of width on resize

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-4

I use Bootstrap 4, so I added following HTML code on my page

**HTML**

```
<div id="device-size-detector">
    <div id="xs" class="d-block d-sm-none"></div>
    <div id="sm" class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none"></div>
    <div id="md" class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none"></div>
    <div id="lg" class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none"></div>
    <div id="xl" class="d-none d-xl-block"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

"use strict"

function getBootstrapDeviceSize() {
    return $('#device-size-detector').find('div:visible').first().attr('id');
}

function checkMenu(){
    var screen = getBootstrapDeviceSize();

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        screen = getBootstrapDeviceSize();
    });

    if(screen == "lg" ||  screen == "xl") {
        console.log(1); 
    } else {
        console.log(0);
    }       
}

checkMenu();

});
```

But my script detects only the first value of screen size and doesn't detect any changes of width on resize. I guess I don't use `$(window).on('resize', function() {...}` properly, but I don't understand how to fix it and make it work?

Comment: you do know bootstrap's width breakpoints are constants right ? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints

Comment: @Stavm aaand what?

Comment: You should place the `console.log` inside the `resize` function. And check if it logs the correct values.

Comment: Yes, it logs correct values if I place `console.log` inside the `resize` function

Comment: So it works then doesn't it?

Comment: @Heidel because to me it looks like you're making it harder than it should be. instead try reading `window.innerWidth`'s value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your `window.resize` code outside of the `checkMenu` function and call the function like below.

```
$(window).on('resize', checkMenu);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

"use strict"

function getBootstrapDeviceSize() {
    return $('#device-size-detector').find('div:visible').first().attr('id');
}

function checkMenu(){
    var screen = getBootstrapDeviceSize();    

    if(screen == "lg" ||  screen == "xl") {
        console.log(1); 
    } else {
        console.log(0);
    }       
}
checkMenu();
$(window).on('resize', checkMenu);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="device-size-detector">
    <div id="xs" class="d-block d-sm-none"></div>
    <div id="sm" class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none"></div>
    <div id="md" class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none"></div>
    <div id="lg" class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none"></div>
    <div id="xl" class="d-none d-xl-block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for help!